# UICollectionViewCell size to fit for all cells on device rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a pager whole screen collectionview. When device rotation, first cell of collectionview is fitting to collectionview on landscape and portrait mode. But when I scroll next cell on collectionview, it is showing two cell. And it is not fitting all screen. How can I fit all cells size to collectionview although I scroll collectionview and rotate. I tried invalideLayout() and many way. But I couldn't achive. Just I only want, collectionviewcell fitted to whole screen in any situation although scroll and rotate.

P.S collectionviewcell size should be whole screen size.

```
public override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape,
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let width = view.frame.height
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait,
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let width = view.frame.width
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width , height:  UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = view.frame.size.width
    return CGSize(width: width , height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
}
```

Comment: What have you written in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Can you share the screenshots ?

Comment: I added my question @iPeter

Comment: Okay. Checking.

Comment: What scrolling direction you want? Horizontal or vertical?

Comment: horizontal @iPeter

Comment: Do you want space between cells?

Comment: @iPeter I updated my last code bro. No my collectionviewcell is whole screen like instagram story. I am developing same scenario for another project. User is scroll horizontally and swiping another whole screen cell.

Comment: You can remove `willTransition`, it won't be needed in my opinion.

Comment: What about using AutoLayout instead of CGSizes? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to remove spacing between your cells like below. This will resolve your problem.

[image]

Comment: yeah they are 0. Can you check my latest code blocks ?

Comment: Remove `willTransition` method.

Comment: and inside `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`, just write `return CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)`.

Comment: Nothing else is needed.

Comment: I deleted and updated. But it is not still working bro. When I scroll to next cell and rotate the device , collectionview show two cell again. It is confidental bro no way to show my code sorry

Comment: Have you removed invalidateLayout?

Comment: Do you any idea?

Comment: I cant do this bro. Its confidental

Answer (score -1):

you have to write your code in viewWillLayoutSubviews(). Like this

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

```
    guard let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
        return
    }



    if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft
    {
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 500)
    }
    else if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight
    {
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 500)
    }

    flowLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Comment: Remove public override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) and func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize method and only set your size in viewWillLayoutSubViews as i mentioned above

Comment: it was so worst

Comment: Is it possible to  put on screenshots? so its better to understands how it really work

Comment: ok. Set both to 0 in Min Spacing  of storybord->Collectionview->SizeInspector

Comment: I think you miss to set Collectionview and cell's content's X postion to 0 and set imageview's image content mode to scale to fill or aspect fill

Comment: How can i do that ?

Comment: storyboard->Imageview->AttributeInspector(Top right)->Content mode(Here change mode to scale to fill or aspect fill)

Comment: No. In indexpath 0 when I rotate device, collectionview works correctly. But when I swipe to indexpath 1, collectionview shows 2 cell. Here is the my problem exactly

Comment: Then you have to share your code if possible because in my code it worked fine.

Comment: what is your skype bro

Comment: I don't use skype. If you have no problem then send it to my mail its dhrmdp254@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

can you try to Apply following Approach.

**1'st Approach**

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

   super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

   // YOUR CODE OR FUNCTIONS CALL HERE

}
```

**2' nd Approach**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
}

deinit {
     NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

func rotated() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape,
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let width = view.frame.height
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait,
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let width = view.frame.width
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width , height:  UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said before, this code is working with first collectionview cell. When I swipe to second cell, collectionview shows two cell. That is my problem

Comment: Can you please put image of cell

Comment: can you please verify CollectionView  sizeForItemAt method call after you swipe first cell and also print size of View in that method.

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        print("collectionViewLayout: width \(view.frame.width), height: \(view.frame.height)")
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }
Now I am working on iphone 8. When I on portrait mode, it prints out width 375.0, height: 667.0, when I on landscape mode width 667.0, height: 375.0